# MongoDB Adding Custom field in aggregate

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

so here's my collection. This consists of users and their data

```
{
  userId: 6udg,
    data: [
       {
        date: 22-09-2022
        hits: 98
       },
      {
       date: 23-09-2022
       hits: 88
      },
      {
       date: 24-09-2022
       hits: 100
      },
      {
       date: 24-11-2022
       hits: 145
      },
      {
       date: 25-11-2022
       hits: 75
      }            
     ]
 },
{
  userId:  7tu5,
    data: [
       {
        date: 22-09-2022
        hits: 98
       },
      {
       date: 23-09-2022
       hits: 88
      },
      {
       date: 24-09-2022
       hits: 100
      },
      {
       date: 24-11-2022
       hits: 18
      },
      {
       date: 25-11-2022
       hits: 65
      }           
     ]
}
```

Here's how I'm creating an aggregate with objects for hits filtered by week, month and year. First I match the user whose data we want to fetch. Then I use projection to get the custom fields that I want.

```
Users.aggregate([
                    {
                        $match: {
                            userId: req.params.userId
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        $project: {
                            _id: 0,
                            last_seven_days: {
                                $filter: {
                                    input: "$data",
                                    as: "index", 
                                    cond: {
                                        $and: [
                                            {
                                                $gte: [
                                                    "$$index.date",
                                                    new Date(moment().utc().startOf("week"))
                                                ]
                                            },
                                            {
                                                $lte: [
                                                    "$$index.date",
                                                    new Date(moment().utc().endOf("week"))
                                                ]
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    }
                                },
                            },
                            last_month: {
                                $filter: {
                                    input: "$data",
                                    as: "index", 
                                    cond: {
                                        $and: [
                                            {
                                                $gte: [
                                                    "$$index.date",
                                                    new Date(moment().utc().startOf("month"))
                                                ]
                                            },
                                            {
                                                $lte: [
                                                    "$$index.date",
                                                    new Date(moment().utc().endOf("month"))
                                                ]
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            last_year: {
                                $filter: {
                                    input: "$data",
                                    as: "index",
                                    cond: {
                                        $and: [
                                            {
                                                $gte: [
                                                    "$$index.date",
                                                    new Date(moment().utc().startOf("year"))
                                                ]
                                            },
                                            {
                                                $lte: [
                                                    "$$index.date",
                                                    new Date(moment().utc().endOf("month"))
                                                ]
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ])
```

what I want to do is add a key called 'average' in each **last_seven_days** , **last_month**, and **last_year** - containing the average hits for week, month and year respectively

Expected output:

```
{
   userId: 6udg
   last_seven_day:[ 
           avg: <avg>
           data:[
                 {
                   date:  24-11-2022,
                   hits: 145,
                 },
                 {
                   date:  25-11-2022,
                   hits: 75,
                 }
               ]
             ]
     }
```

Comment: Look into [$reduce](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/), I think it'll do what you need

Comment: Please post valid json documents for sample data and expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply add another projection step:

```
 db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      last_seven_day: {
        data: "$last_seven_day_arr",
        avg: {
          $avg: "$last_seven_day_arr.hits"
        }
      },
      last_month: {
        data: "$last_month_arr",
        avg: {
          $avg: "$last_month_arr.hits"
        }
      },
      last_year: {
        data: "$last_year_arr",
        avg: {
          $avg: "$last_year_arr.hits"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

See how it works on the [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/XzDODoyOhsR)

Comment: but is it possible to have last_seven_day_average inside last_seven_days field?

Comment: Sure. You can do it like [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/XzDODoyOhsR)

Comment: This is awesome. I did not know you can project again. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$filter` to filter the records first. Then use another `$avg` to compute the average in filtered result.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      userId: "6udg"
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "last_seven_days": {
        data: {
          "$filter": {
            "input": "$data",
            "as": "d",
            "cond": {
              $lt: [
                {
                  "$dateDiff": {
                    "startDate": "$$d.date",
                    "endDate": "$$NOW",
                    "unit": "day"
                  }
                },
                7
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "last_month": {
        data: {
          "$filter": {
            "input": "$data",
            "as": "d",
            "cond": {
              $lt: [
                {
                  "$dateDiff": {
                    "startDate": "$$d.date",
                    "endDate": "$$NOW",
                    "unit": "month"
                  }
                },
                1
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "last_year": {
        data: {
          "$filter": {
            "input": "$data",
            "as": "d",
            "cond": {
              $lt: [
                {
                  "$dateDiff": {
                    "startDate": "$$d.date",
                    "endDate": "$$NOW",
                    "unit": "year"
                  }
                },
                1
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "last_seven_days": {
        avg: {
          $avg: "$last_seven_days.data.hits"
        }
      },
      "last_month": {
        avg: {
          $avg: "$last_month.data.hits"
        }
      },
      "last_year": {
        avg: {
          $avg: "$last_year.data.hits"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Cuf28Zdn8Bv)